# $\min_z\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k\right|$ for $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

**Question**

Suppose $z$ is some complex number satisfying $|z|=1$. Is there a way to simplify the expression
$$\min_{z}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k\right|$$
to something that can be easily computed given real numbers $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^n$?

---

**My attempt**

Write $z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ and use De Moivre's formula to get $z^k=\cos(k\theta)+i\sin(k\theta)$. Then, we get
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k (\cos(k\theta)+i \sin(k\theta))\right|.$$
Euler's formula, then allows us to write
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k e^{k\theta i}\right|.$$
So the problem would reduce to that of solving
$$\min_{\theta}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k e^{k\theta i}\right|.$$
This seems like it could help but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I tried with $az^2+bz+c$ and $az^3+bz^2+cz+d$ but found no nice simplification.

Comment: This is a good idea, to try simple cases. For the quadratic case, the last minimization yields $\theta=-i \ln(-a_1/(2a_2))$ and then the minimum becomes $-(a_1^2-4a_0a_2)/(4a_2).$

Comment: In general there is no way to find this minimum. For example, if the polynomial under consideration has a root on the circle then the minimum zero. However, one can find upper bound by integrating the polynomial square, i.e.computing its $L^2$ norm. Clearly, this on is $\sqrt{\sum |a_k|^2}$, hence the minimum is bounded by this value.

Comment: Hello mzp, I recognize the question :). It's easier to calculate $min |\cdot|^2$. This leads to an expression $\sum c_k \cos(k\theta)$. Using Chebyshev polynomials $T_k(\cos(\theta)=\cos(k\theta)$ you get a generic polynomial of degree $n$. So the important question is: Do you have any additional conditions / special cases such that it breaks down to a manageable problem.

Comment: @TomTom314 Yes, your answer lead me to this :) I guess one special case of interest would be $a_i=a^i$. Would you mind writing out what you describe in your comment as an answer with a bit more detail?

Comment: @Salcio Could you point me to some reference about how to compute the $L^2$ norm by integrating the polynomial square? I think this could help me since $|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k|=|a_0 - \sum_{k=1}^n (-a_k) z^k|\ge \left||a_0| - |\sum_{k=1}^n (-a_k) z^k|\right|=\left||a_0| - \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2}\right|$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Check any book (like Rudin's Introduction to Real Analysis), this is just integral of the second power of the absolute value of polynomial.

Comment: It seems no easy way: $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k\right|^2 = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k (\cos(k\theta)+i \sin(k\theta))\right|^2 = \sum_{r, s = 0}^n a_r a_s \cos ((r - s)\theta).$$